# После запуска cluster.fork(). Почему при команде kill "numActiveProcess" перестает работать setInterval. Где взаимосвязь?

Tags: node.js, события

Почему при команде kill (номер запущенного процесса) перестает работать интервал с номером этого процесса?

```
if(cluster.isMaster) {
    for (let i = 0; i < os.cpus().length - 2; i++) { // пару ядер для ОС
        cluster.fork()
} else {
    console.log(`Воркер с pid: ${process.pid} запущен`);

    setInterval(() => { // вопрос в этом интервале
        console.log(`Воркер с pid ${process.pid} еще работает`);
    }, 4000);
}
```

*Например*, после запуска программы, создалось 2 процесса: 8081 и 19056 - работали 2 интервала на них. После команды kill 8081 - interval на нем перестает работать, Но ведь мы заранее его создали. Где взаимосвязь закрытия процесса с прекращением работы одного из интервалов?

Я бы понял, если бы при убийстве процесса, начались бы сообщения в консоль "Воркер с pid undefined еще работает", но совсем ничего нет. По логике, даже после команды kill все равно каждые 4 секунды должен работать interval. Что я упускаю?

Comment: Эээ, что? `setInterval` работает *внутри* процесса воркера. Если вы его убили, то с никакого setInterval он уже не может выполнить…

Comment: Так, значит, я что-то кардинально не понимаю в организации распределения потоков

Comment: Собсна говоря, я понимаю, что даже не понимаю, с какого перепуга коду удается зайти в блок "else"... 
На этом, пожалуй все)
Пасиб за понимание - только начал учить ноду

Comment: В новом потоке созданном методом `cluster.fork()` весь скрипт начинает исполняться с самого начала (собственно это легко проверить добавив в самое начала скрипта какой-нибудь console.log). Но в процессах порождённых `fork`-ом свойство `cluster.isMaster` будет `false` и выполнится код в `else`.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек. Очень доступно объяснил. 
Делай то же сообщение ответом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Alexey Ten](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten) дал ответ на вопрос - вот дословно: "В новом потоке созданном методом cluster.fork() весь скрипт начинает исполняться с самого начала (собственно это легко проверить добавив в самое начала скрипта какой-нибудь console.log). Но в процессах порождённых fork-ом свойство cluster.isMaster будет false и выполнится код в else."